# .htaccess show indexes, grant file access only with login

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I try to secure .html files inside a directory with .htaccess.
The directory index should still be visibe without login.
I created following:

```
Order allow,deny
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secured Area - Enter password!"
AuthUserFile .htusers                     

Options +Indexes
IndexOptions HtmlTable FancyIndexing IconsAreLinks SuppressRules SuppressSize
IndexIgnore ..

<Files "(\.htaccess|\.htusers)">
        Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "(.*\.html)">
        Require valid-user
</Files>
```

But with it, access to all is forbitten. I tried several combinations, but nor success. So maybe someone can help?

Comment: Either use `FilesMatch` with a negated expression that excludes the `index.html`, or add a `Files` directive specifically for `index.html`, specify `Allow from all` in there, and combine that with the `Require` using `Satisfy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The users file in configuration above has to be in root directory. That solves the problem.